# nc: command not found while setting up Apache Samza

Tags: apache-kafka, git-bash, apache-zookeeper, apache-samza

When i try to setup Apache Samza, i get nc command not found when starting zookeeper.
I'm running the command:

```
bin/grid bootstrap
```

i get

```
/c/..../hello-samza/bin/grid: line 170: nc: command not found
```

I'm writing the command in git bash console on windows 10 Education.
I'm new to samza and git bash in general. How can i fix this or is there a way to integrate nc commands in git bash basic commands?
or am i running the commands in the wrong console ?

Comment: nc is Netcat (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). I have no clue how to get it working on Windows 10 however. Samza is extensively tested on Linux, with very little testing done on Windows.

Comment: @JonBringhurst i know the commands are netcat and it got its errors on linux too, i contacted samza developers when i posted this question and they haven't replied yet so i was hoping someone would have encountered this problem before.